# How to load fxml in splitpane's childpane, left or right child pane?

Tags: javafx, splitpane

```
public void startQuiz(ActionEvent ae) {

    try {
        mainPane.setVisible(true);//main splitpane      
        AnchorPane newPane = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TestFXML.fxml"));
        mainPane.getItems().set(1, newPane);//don't know loading in either left or right Anchorpane
        labelPane.setVisible(false);//previous child pane to hide
        mainPane.setVisible(true);
        menuPane.setVisible(true);//right pane
    } catch (Exception ex) {//`errors is in loading pane`
        errorAlert.setContentText("" + ex);
        errorAlert.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: A split pane's [`items`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html#getItems--) are ordered as they appear in the split pane. So if this is a horizontal split pane, `mainPane.getItems().set(1, newPane)` will set the second item, reading from left to right.

Comment: thanks I also did this